# How can I create a new column using an if else statement regarding two columns from two different dataframes?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes (df1, df2).  I would like to create a new 'score' column in df2 that would follow an ifelse statement.

````
If Else Statement:
If pn1=pn2 & sub1=sub2, then score = 2, 
elseif pn1=pn2 & sub1 IS IN sub2, then score = 1, 
elseif pn=pn, then score = 0,
else score = NA. 
```
    pn1 <- c('12345','12345','13579', '01289','22468')

    sub1 <- c('01','x001','hi-02','bye','12')

    pn2 <- c('12345','12345','13579', '01289','22468','28245')

    sub2 <- c('01','x002','hi-2','b','xyz','23')

    row <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

    df1 <- data.frame(pn1,sub1)

    df2 <- data.frame(row,pn2,sub2)

    #Desired Output 
    score <- c(2,1,1,1,0,'NA')

    df2$score <- score
```
For further explanation on the if statement:
Row 1- Score = 2 because PN1 = PN2 and SUB1=SUB2.
Row 2,3,4- Score = 1 because PN1 = PN2 and SUB1 can be found in SUB2.
Row 5- Score = 0 because PN1=PN2.
Row 6- Score = NA because PN2 is not found in df1.
````

Comment: Two questions: 1) How do you want to compare rows in `df1` to rows in `df2`? (e.g. do you want to compare row 1 of `df1` to row 1 of `df2`, then row 2 of `df1` to row 2 of `df2`, etc?) 2) What is your definition of the `IS IN` operator? You seem to be saying that "x001" IS IN "x002" evaluates to true, and I don't know for which operator that would be so.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your question as the dimensions of the two data frames are different. Also, in your example it does not appear to me that the 2nd-4th indices would evaluate to 1 as SUB1 is not in SUB2 in these cases. This answer is based off what you describe you want and not what you've shown you want if that makes sense.

```
df1 <- data.frame(pn1,sub1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(row,pn2,sub2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
df2$score <- case_when(df2$pn2 == df1$pn1 & df2$sub2 == df1$sub1 ~ 2,
                       df2$pn2 %in% df1$pn1 & df2$sub2 %in% df1$sub1 ~ 1,
                       df2$pn2 %in% df1$pn1 & !(df2$sub2 %in% df1$sub1) ~ 0,
                       !(df2$pn2 %in% df1$pn1) ~ NA_real_)
```